# Apache only serving files from /var/www/html

Tags: ubuntu, apache2

I'm using Apache2 in Ubuntu with the mod_mono module as a local ASP.NET server.

As of yet, Apache is only able to serve my simple.aspx file when it is located in the standard `/var/www/html` directory.

When I put the file in its own directory `/var/www/mysite` and enable its own configuration `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite.conf` with `sudo a2ensite mysite`:

```
  1 <VirtualHost *:80>                                                                                                                                                                                                
  2         DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite                                                                                                                                                                                 
  3         <Directory /var/www/net>                                                                                                                                                                                  
  4             require all granted                                                                                                                                                                                   
  5         </Directory>                                                                                                                                                                                              
  6         ServerName simple                                                                                                                                                                                         
  7 </VirtualHost>
```

I get an http 404 resource not found error when browsing to `http://localhost/simple` or `http://localhost/mysite/simple.aspx`.

I get the same result when trying to white-list the `/var/www/mysite` directory in the global `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` configuration file:

```
170 <Directory /var/www/mysite/>                                                                                                                                                                                         
171         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks                                                                                                                                                                            
172         AllowOverride None                                                                                                                                                                                        
173         Require all granted                                                                                                                                                                                       
174 </Directory>
```

No, I did not forget to restart apache after changing a configuration.

I have the following permissions

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root  root  4096 Nov 11 18:50 html
drwxrwxr-x 2 prive www-data 4096 Nov 11 18:59 mysite\
```

How do I need to configure apache in order for it to serve files for a different folder then `/var/www/html`?

Comment: @Messè Redi you don't have any virtualhost with the server name localhost and your request is going to the default virtualhost, your virtualhost "ServerName simple"

Comment: @c4f4t0r In my global configuration I have the statement `Servername localhost`.

Comment: @c4f4t0r Could you elaborate on why this is relevant?

Comment: You need to do some reading on Name-Based Virtual Hosting. Try https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html, although it is somewhat light on how this relates to HTTP. Basically, the HTTP request contains a 'Host' header (eg. `Host: serverfault.com`), which is distinct from say `Host: stackexchange.com`). The Host header gets sent based on what you put into the browser URL bar. eg. http://serverfault.com/blah would result in a Host header of 'Host: serverfault.com'. Your example would require a URL of http://simple/, which is likely not what you're wantinge

Comment: @MusséRedi read Cameron Kerr comment.

Comment: @c4f4t0r I did. :) I learned that in name-based virtual hosting you need to use the hosts file, so that apache gets both the ip (via the hosts file) and a domain name (via the url that you put into the web-browser). This allows apache to resolve the request to the ServerName listed in the virtual host configuration.

Comment: @CameronKerr Is there a way to achieve my goal of accessing my virtual host through a browser without using the hosts file? My guess is that this is inherently impossible because apache needs both an ip address and a name in order to resolve to the vs. But is there some kind of URL that can do this without using the hosts file? I'm just wondering...

Comment: Have a look at xip.io. It provides a virtual sort of DNS service. Eg.  192.168.1.2.xip.io is a hostname that when looked up resolves to the address 192.168.1.2. No config necessary. You could then have a certificate with that hostname, or put this as a ServerName or ServerAlias.  Of course, normally you just set up the right entries in DNS, but this is a good option for development